# Access Gatsby Component from a function

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to access a Gatsby component (Anime) from outside of it.
Can not figure out what instance name this would have or how to name it.
Here is my code:

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
    import PreviewCompatibleImage from '../components/PreviewCompatibleImage'
    import Anime from 'react-anime';
    import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

    function onChange (isVisible) {
     console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
     }  

    const FeatureGrid = ({ gridItems }) => (
      <div className="columns is-multiline">
      <VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange}>
      <Anime delay={(e, i) => i * 100}
             scale={[.1, .9]}
             autoplay={false}>
        {gridItems.map(item => (
          <div key={item.text} className="column is-3">
            <section className="section">
              <div className="has-text-centered">
                <div
                  style={{
                    width: '160px',
                    display: 'inline-block',
                  }}
                >
                  <PreviewCompatibleImage imageInfo={item} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>{item.text}</p>
            </section>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Anime>
      </VisibilitySensor>
      </div>
    )

    FeatureGrid.propTypes = {
      gridItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          image: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.string]),
          text: PropTypes.string,
        })
      ),
    }

    export default FeatureGrid
```

I want to get the animation to trigger from the onChange function.
How do I get the name or set the name of the Anime component so I can access it from the function?
Or is there another way I should address this?

Using a Gatsby starter netlify CMS as the base, so extending on their code, but seems that `const` is not the route I should take.

I want the animation to trigger when it becomes visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you see the `reactive animations` example here https://alain.xyz/libraries/react-anime ?

Comment: @ksav I did, but the example is based on render while the starter uses export in each page, don't know how to implement the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs [react-visibility-sensor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-visibility-sensor) :

> You can pass a child function, which can be convenient if you don't need to store the visibility anywhere

so maybe instead of using the onchange function you can just pass the **isVisible** parameter, something like:

```
<VisibilitySensor>
  {({isVisible}) =>
     <Anime delay={(e, i) => i * 100}
         // the rest of your codes here ...
     </Anime>
  }
</VisibilitySensor>
```

Otherwise you can convert this function to a react component and set states, etc..